# Django page that uploads csv in memory and sends off json to api

Tags: python-3.x, django, rest, django-views

I am attempting to use django to make a site that interacts with an api for the user. The first page of the site needs to be a csv upload, that then parses the data into a json format and sends if off to the api.

I've gone through the django tutorial for the polls app, and have a minimal understanding of django. But it is really overwhelming.

I was able to get the csv upload from this site working: [csv upload](https://simathapa111.medium.com/how-to-upload-a-csv-file-in-django-3a0d6295f624)

But that stores the data to a model. (Which may ultimately be ok.) But I was thinking that I could just upload the csv and convert it straight to a json without storing it?

I think I'm just looking for some direction on how to have a simple upload where the upload buttom is just a submit that triggers the csv ingestion, formatting, and api request.  The only thing I think I need to store is the response from the request. (It returns an ID that I need in order to retrieve the results through a different API call.)

I also notices that the current view only updates the table with new rows. So I was able to add "profile.objects.all().delete()" before the csv read loop in order to empty the table before each upload.

CSV Upload:

```
name,email,address,phone,profile
Sima,simathapa111@gmail.com,Nadipur,14151234567,"She is a developer, researcher and food-lover."
Gita,geeta12@outlook.com,Pokhara,(415) 123-4567,"Geeta is a teacher, she loves to play and dance."
Ram,ram123@gmail.com,Kathmandu,17735356563,Ram delivers food.
```

JSON Format:

```
{
    "peopleRecords": [
        {
            "name": "Sima",
            "email": "simathapa111@gmail.com",
            "address": "Nadipur",
            "phone": "14151234567",
            "profile": "She is a developer, researcher and food-lover."
        },
        {
            "name": "Gita",
            "email": "geeta12@outlook.com",
            "address": "Pokhara",
            "phone": "(415) 123-4567",
            "profile": "Geeta is a teacher, she loves to play and dance."
        },
        {
            "name": "Ram",
            "email": "ram123@gmail.com",
            "address": "Kathmandu",
            "phone": "17735356563",
            "profile": "Ram delivers food."
        }
]}
```

Model:

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=150,unique=True)
    profile = models.TextField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Admin:

```
from django.contrib import admin
# Register your models here.
from .models import Profile
admin.site.register(Profile)
```

View:

```
import csv, io
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import messages
# Create your views here.
# one parameter named request
def profile_upload(request):
    # declaring template
    template = "profile_upload.html"
    data = Profile.objects.all()
# prompt is a context variable that can have different values      depending on their context
    prompt = {
        'order': 'Order of the CSV should be name, email, address,    phone, profile',
        'profiles': data    
              }
    # GET request returns the value of the data with the specified key.
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, template, prompt)
    csv_file = request.FILES['file']
    # let's check if it is a csv file
    if not csv_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
        messages.error(request, 'THIS IS NOT A CSV FILE')
    data_set = csv_file.read().decode('UTF-8')
    # setup a stream which is when we loop through each line we are able to handle a data in a stream
io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
next(io_string)
for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar="|"):
    _, created = Profile.objects.update_or_create(
        name=column[0],
        email=column[1],
        address=column[2],
        phone=column[3],
        profile=column[4]
    )
context = {}
return render(request, template, context)
```

Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            <div>
<!--                | means OR operator-->
                <strong>{{message|safe}}</strong>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
    {{order}}
    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="file1"> Upload a file</label>
        <input type="file" id="file1" name="file">
        <small>Only accepts CSV files</small>
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
    {% endif %}
    {% for profile in profiles %}
    {{profile.name}}
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

URL:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from csvfile.views import profile_upload

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('upload-csv/', profile_upload, name="profile_upload"),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can put information in json without saving it in the database. But in any case you have to save the csv file and then work on that file. Once you have saved the file, you can even do the same with a similar piece of code below:

```
csv_file = open("csv_file.csv")
csv_file.readline()  # To cross the first line.
data = []
for line in csv_file:
    name, email, address, phone, profile = line.split(",")
    data.append({
        "name": name,
        "email": email,
        "address": address,
        "phone": phone,
        "profile": profile
    })

# return data ...
```